# Using 'this.currentTime' to get the time of a video and reset it to the starting point on 'hover out'

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I have a video library where I want to dynamically use the Media Fragment time in URL as the poster.
When hovering out, **I am trying to reset the video to the initial start - to make sure the poster is at 2 seconds (in this specific example) instead of 0.**

this.load works but creates a bad user experience as the whole video loads in again.

My idea is to define the current time as a variable (before the video starts playing) and use it when pausing the video.

However I just get "Uncaught ReferenceError: posterTime is not defined".

```
<video id="video">
  <source src="videourl.mp4#t=2" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```
const videos = document.querySelectorAll("video")

  videos.forEach(video => {

    video.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
        var posterTime = this.currentTime;
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play()
    })
    
    video.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
      this.currentTime = posterTime;
      this.pause();
    })
  })
```

*Note that I use Webflow and is not very strong with jQuery/Javascript.*

Comment: Why do you need to get/set the currentTime at all if you're pausing the video on mouseout, and resetting it back to the start on mouseover? Removing that logic the code seems to do what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/7s3q0mjk/. Regarding the error you have , it's because you define the `posterTime` variable only in the scope of the `mouseover` event handler.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!

I need it in order to show the initial frame/poster of the video. That frame will dynamically be set through the URL (eg: http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4#t=5).

As I hover out I need it to show that initial frame again (not the first frame, but the one set in the URL). However the video should always start playing at 0 seconds.

It's the concept that you see here: https://steep.design/
I am just trying to achieve it without a JPEG poster as the initial frame.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying - I added an answer below to give you an example of how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *My idea is to define the current time as a variable (before the video
> starts playing) and use it when pausing the video. However I just get
> **"Uncaught ReferenceError: posterTime is not defined"**.*

Your idea and code is fine but you made a basic mistake.
**Remember**: A variable defined inside a function will exist only for that function where it was created.

Use `let` for internal variables (where possible) and use `var` for global variables.

**solution**: Define the variable as **global** (outside of any functions)...

```
const videos = document.querySelectorAll("video");
var posterTime = -1; //# global var, with starting value...
 
videos.forEach(video => {

    video.addEventListener("mouseover", function () 
    {
        posterTime = this.currentTime; //# set time
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play()
    })

    video.addEventListener("mouseout", function () 
    {
        this.currentTime = posterTime; //# get time
        this.pause();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> As I hover out I need it to show that initial frame again (not the first frame, but the one set in the URL)

Given this requirement you can retrieve the fragment from the URL in the `src` attribute of the `source` element and apply it to the `currentTime` of the video when the `mouseleave` event occurs:

```js
const videos = document.querySelectorAll("video")

videos.forEach(video => {
  video.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play()
  })

  video.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    let src = this.querySelector('source').src;
    let time = (src.split('#')[1] || 't=0').split('=')[1];
    this.currentTime = time;
    this.pause();
  })
})
```

```html
<video id="video">
  <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4#t=5" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: You probably want to mute before the sync, there's a pop on Firefox